# How can I fix the behaviour of special function keys in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, function-keys

I have a fairly basic Advent keyboard with backlit keys. The colour of the backlight is controlled with a special modifier key on the keyboard + F1/2/3/4.

Since around the time of updating to Windows 8.1 and updating to UEFI BIOS on my GA-Z68X-3BH, these brightness controls don't work unless I unplug the USB connector and plug it back in (a nuisance). I've recently realised that they also work outside of Windows, with the backlight level then remaining fixed at whatever level I set it at (including after sleeping).

FWIW I've tried SharpKeys, which doesn't even notice when I press the light modifier key (or subsequent modified Fx keys).

Any help much appreciated... I won't be at all surprised if I add to my collection of tumbleweed badges with this question...

Comment: The light modifier key won't be a regular key that sends scan codes to the OS.  Therefor no software can see it (short of drivers offered by the manufacturer, if they implemented that). Maybe try adjusting the OSs power/sleep settings for the USB controller(s) and port(s)?

Comment: Worth poking around those settings I suppose; will have to restart the machine to see any effect, since it's now in it's working mode. I did search for drivers briefly, but I'm pretty sure there are none (no surprise).

Comment: No joy with power settings for the USB controllers etc AFAICT, but thanks @techie007 for the suggestion. I have noticed that after unplugging / replugging then activating lights, it *doesn't* remember the light setting after sleep in the same way as it does if I set it before it gets into Windows.

Comment: I changed some settings in the BIOS and now it works... not sure what made the difference. Maybe disabling ps/2 emulation or something.

Comment: Hmmm... haven't changed any BIOS settings etc since my last comment, but now notice the keys not working again...